# Validar campos antes de crear un objeto en java

Tags: java, java-swing, validación, jtextfield

Tengo este método que me valida algunos campos antes de poder crear un objeto para persistirlo en la base de datos. Lanzo excepciones para saber que campo es incorrecto y mostrarlo en un joptionpane

```
public void crearProducto() throws Exception {
        if (isCamposProductoVacios()) {
            throw new Exception("Debe completar todos los campos");
        }
        if (!isPrecioProductoCorrecto()) {
            throw new Exception("Debe ingresar un numero mayor a cero para el precio del producto");
        }

        if (!isStockProductoCorrecto()) {
            throw new Exception("Debe ingresar un numero mayor a cero para el stock del producto");
        }
        producto = new Producto();
        if (!txtIdProducto.getText().equals("")) {
            producto.setId(Long.parseLong(txtIdProducto.getText()));
        }
        producto.setNombre(txtNombreProducto.getText());
        producto.setPrecio(Double.parseDouble(txtPrecioProducto.getText()));
        producto.setStock(Integer.parseInt(txtStockProducto.getText()));
        producto.setEstado(true);
        producto.setCategoria(categoriaService.buscarPorNombre(cmbCategoriaProductos.getSelectedItem().toString()));
    }
```

Quiero separar los if's y el seteo de los valores en dos métodos diferentes. Me quedaría así:

```
public void crearProducto() throws Exception {
        validarCampos();
        setearValores();
    }
    
    public void validarCampos() throws Exception {
        if (isCamposProductoVacios()) {
            throw new Exception("Debe completar todos los campos");
        }
        if (!isPrecioProductoCorrecto()) {
            throw new Exception("Debe ingresar un numero mayor a cero para el precio del producto");
        }
        if (!isStockProductoCorrecto()) {
            throw new Exception("Debe ingresar un numero mayor a cero para el stock del producto");
        }
    }

    public void setearValores() throws Exception {
        producto = new Producto();
        if (!txtIdProducto.getText().equals("")) {
            producto.setId(Long.parseLong(txtIdProducto.getText()));
        }
        producto.setNombre(txtNombreProducto.getText());
        producto.setPrecio(Double.parseDouble(txtPrecioProducto.getText()));
        producto.setStock(Integer.parseInt(txtStockProducto.getText()));
        producto.setEstado(true);
        producto.setCategoria(categoriaService.buscarPorNombre(cmbCategoriaProductos.getSelectedItem().toString()));
    }
```

Mi duda es si es incorrecto que el metodo validarCampos solo sirva para lanzar excepciones

Comment: Si mueves toda la lógica de `is???()` a `validarCampos()` encapsularías la *lógica de negocio* en ése método; como lo tienes actualmente dicha lógica queda muy dispersa; llevar las funciones al límite de la simplicidad resulta en el código más complejo que te puedas imaginar.

Comment: No entiendo cuál es tu punto

Comment: ¿Qué no quedó claro? alguna retroalimentación de tu parte nos ayudaría. Replanteo con un par de ligas: Si mueves el código de `is???()` a `validarCampos()` [encapsularías](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulamiento_\(inform%C3%A1tica\)) convenientemente la [lógica de negocio](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B3gica_de_negocio) en ése método.

Answer (score 0):

Yo creo que si es un error ocupar las Exceptions de esa manera. Los Exceptions son para errores de código, son netamente de programación y se deberían producir cuando tu programa no puede continuar porque algo falló.

En mi filosofía de programación, yo trato de evitarlos dentro de lo posible. Siempre validando antes de que se produzca el error.

Lo que veo que tú tienes es un flujo normal de tu programa, que es cuando todos los campos están bien y un flujo alternativo que es cuando los campos no cumplen ciertas condiciones. Pero ambos flujos son parte de tu programa, no son excepciones.

Yo haría algo así:

```
public void crearProducto() {
        if(validarCampos()){
          setearValores();
        }  
    }
    
    public bool validarCampos() {
        if (isCamposProductoVacios()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(myJFrame, "Debe completar todos los campos");
            return false;
        }
        else if (!isPrecioProductoCorrecto()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(myJFrame, "Debe ingresar un numero mayor a cero para el precio del producto");
            return false;
        }
        else if (!isStockProductoCorrecto()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(myJFrame, "Debe ingresar un numero mayor a cero para el stock del producto");
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: En realidad lanzó excepciones porque quiero que me muestre cual es el campo incorrecto, una función booleana no es suficiente

Comment: Si quieres alertar al desarrollador debes ocupar excepciones, si quieres alertar al usuario debes ocupar otro método, ya sea una ventana emergente, un campo de texto o un cambio de color en los textbox

Comment: También pensé en mostralos con joptionpanes dentro de la función booleana, como muestras en tu respuesta. Pero no incumple la regla de que una función solo debe hacer una cosa? Ya que valida y muestra mensajes a la vez

Comment: Esa no es una regla, como mucho es una pauta o recomendación. No hay que ser extremistas con estos aspectos, lo importante es que sea legible. Ahora bien, si tienes más validaciones podrías crear una clase ValidacionRespuesta con 2 funciones isValid() y GetError(), entonces la función validarCampos retorna un ValidacionRespuesta. Pero si solo fuera este caso sería complejizar más el asunto

Comment: Considera la clase [`UserException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/omg/CORBA/UserException.html). En [CORBA](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORBA) también se rompió el paradigma de uso exclusivo de excepciones para el programador. El uso de bitácoras se popularizó al mismo tiempo.